# gedit - wrap text with character boxes

Tags: gedit, plugins, text-editor, text

I use gedit for pure text writing (I mean not coding). To highlight chapters in the text I wrap with "+" boxes likes:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
  Title goes here
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

or do underline by using "---".

To streamline the writing I was looking for a plugin with no success. Not looking for any advanced editor. Wanted just pure text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This facility already exists in Gedit in the 'Snippets' section. First ensure you have activated the Snippets pluging by opening Gedit and then going to:

```
Edit --> Preferences --> Plugins
```

and activate the Plugin as shown here:

[image]

Then go to:

```
Tools --> Manage Snippets
```

and finally:

1. Define a new snippet by using the '+' key and name it
2. Type your preferred letters in the 'Edit' section
3. Add a shortcut key to it

Below is my own version of what you are after, which I have named 'Code Marker' and mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

This is now available in your all of your Gedit documents; not a pure 'wrap' but pretty close to it :)

**A note of caution:** Be a little cautious of which keys you assign as shortcuts to avoid conflicts with default gedit shortcuts that might [already be claiming these keys...](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en)

Comment: You could check with https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en before assigning a key combo to avoid conflicts with existing shortcuts. Ctrl+T may already be set to open a new tab.

Comment: @DKBose: great point, which I have absorbed into my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Work great. I thought it was only for coding, but I see the global works for all. To avoid shortcut key conflicts, decided to use a tab trigger "tbox" that writes a "full box", I mean a "+" line up and down with a blank line in the middle to write the title.